# React not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, rerender

When i moved my code to a newer version of react for some reason its not rendering and updating 'total votes' when i click on any of the below buttons.

Edit: Also when i tried to print my data in the async functions, it comes up as null, but i checked my database and it does get updated.

Component below:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import ProgressBar from "../ProgessBar"

const QuestionCard = ({ questionData, onDelete, supabase }) => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null);
  const [yes, setYes] = useState(questionData.votesYes);
  const [no, setNo] = useState(questionData.votesNo);
  //get user session
  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session)
    })
    //watches for changes in session
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session)
    })
  
  }, [])

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('questions')
      .delete()
      .eq('id', questionData.id)

    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(data)
      onDelete(questionData.id)
    }
  }

  const handleYes = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('questions')
      .update({ votesYes: questionData.votesYes + 1, votesTotal: questionData.votesTotal + 1})
      .eq('id', questionData.id)
    if (error) {
      console.log('errored: ' + error);
    }
    if (data) {
      //sets yes hook state
      setYes(data[0].votesYes);
      
    }
  }

  const handleNo = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('questions')
      .update({ votesNo: questionData.votesNo + 1, votesTotal: questionData.votesTotal + 1})
      .eq('id', questionData.id)
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    if (data) {
      setNo(data[0].votesNo);
    }
  }
  const handlePollingResult = () => {
  }

  return (
    <div className="question-card">
      <h4>{questionData.question}</h4>
      <div className="polling-results">
        <h5>Total Votes: {yes + no}</h5>
      </div>
      <div><ProgressBar questionData={questionData}/></div>
      <div className="buttons">
        {!session ? <i>Please Sign in to vote</i> : <i className="yes-btn" onClick={handleYes}>Yes</i>}
        {!session ? <i></i> : <i className="no-btn" onClick={handleNo}>No</i>}
        {!session ? <i></i> : <i className="delete-btn" id='delete-btn' onClick={handleDelete}>delete</i>}
        {!session ? <i></i> : <i className="polling-result-btn" onClick={handlePollingResult}>Results data</i>}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default QuestionCard
```

When clicking on any of my buttons, i expected it to re-render the page and update the values, however it doesn't seem to happen please let me know if you need more information, this is my first post :)

Comment: using `questionData.votesYes++;` looks like a red flag. You are mutating the variable value in the callback. On next rendender this change will be lost because the parent of this component will just pass the prop again without knowing about the change that happened in this component

Comment: Thanks, i've adjusted my code accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a useEffect to fix this issue, and everytime i pressed the button i made sure to set the boolean in dependancy array to true:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('I rendered!');
const renderPage = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('questions')
    .select()
    .eq('id', questionData.id)

  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  if (data) {
    console.log(data)
    setYes(data[0].votesYes);
    setNo(data[0].votesNo);
  }
}
render && renderPage();
setRender(false);
}, [render])
```